# Localizing an iOS Smart App Banner

Tags: ios, mobile-safari

I've created a smart app banner for a client, but am having trouble making the banner show up in French (still shows up in English) if the user's device is set to French. The iOS App supports both English (default) and Canadian French.

Does anyone know of a way to do this? The Apple documentation (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html) doesn't offer any insights into localization.

Thanks!